# An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the ImportCertificate operation: The private key is not supported

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am using the AWS CLI in order to import a certificate to region `us-east-1`, like so:

```
aws acm import-certificate --certificate cert.crt --private-key private.key --certificate-chain chain.crt --profile prof --region us-east-1
```

This has worked in the past for other certs, however I recently started seeing the following error:

```
An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the ImportCertificate operation: The private key is not supported.
```

I have checked that the private key indeed matches the certificate via openssl, so I am quite lost as to what might be the issue here.

```
openssl rsa -in private.key -check
```

yields

```
RSA key ok
```

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just ran into this as well and found a hint elsewhere that suggested prefixing your file with "file://".  Worked for me.  Give it a try:

```
aws acm import-certificate --certificate file://cert.crt --private-key file://private.key --certificate-chain file://chain.crt --profile prof --region us-east-1
```

Answer (score 0):

In `MAC OS`, we need to prefix with `file:///`, triple `/` slash instead of two.

```
aws acm import-certificate --certificate "file:///cert.crt" --private-key "file:///private.key" --certificate-chain "file:///chain.crt" --profile prof --region us-east-1
```